# How to use Parallel Controller with Throughput controller in Jmeter

Tags: parallel-processing, jmeter

I am facing one weird challenge while setting up Jmeter script. We got a requirement of executing parallel request which we are able to achieve via using 'bzm-parallel controller.' Now next part is we need to divide those requests further and give them load % without losing their parallelism.
I have tried below setup (setup1 and setup2) but aint getting expected results.

```
setup1
#TestPlan1
##Ultimate thread group 
Ultimate thread group 
> Throughput_controller_1_HomePage (50%)
>> bzm- Parallel controller
>>> API Req 1
>>> API Req 2
>>> API Req 3
> Throughput_controller_2_HomePage (30%)
>> bzm- Parallel controller
>>> API Req 4
>>> API Req 5
> Throughput_controller_3_NextPage (20%)
>> API Req 6
```

With setup1 I see requests are almost parallelly executed but don't see any evidence of Throughput controller and % weight given to it is working.

```
setup2
#TestPlan2
##Ultimate thread group 
> bzm- Parallel controller
>> Throughput_controller_1_HomePage (50%)
>>> API Req 1
>>> API Req 2
>>> API Req 3
> bzm- Parallel controller
>> Throughput_controller_2_HomePage (30%)
>>> API Req 4
>>> API Req 5
> Throughput_controller_3_NextPage (20%)
>> API Req 6
```

With setup2 I see requests which are inside both parallel controllers are not executed at all. And only 'API Req 6' got executed by Jmeter. *Can anyone please help me or guide me to resolve this chanllenge*

Answer (score 0):

Parallel Controller executes all its children at the same time by kicking off extra virtual threads, it allows JMeter to simulate network footprint for specific use cases like simulating [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).

If you want to run parallel requests - just increase the number of threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to reach the desired concurrency.

If you want to run a request with X users at exactly the same moment - take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

If you want to simulate different groups of business users - use different Thread Groups

If you want to run different requests at different percentages or weights - use Throughput Controller or [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/weighted-switch-controller-jmeter)

The combination you defined is neither supported nor makes sense.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897748/dmitri-t Thank you for detailed explanation. We are looking to simulate scenario where X users access home page of app where all API 1 to 6 are loaded, and then other API (pages) are loaded after scroll down or with any activity on the page. So, I am looking for combining parallel request and then some request based on % weight.

Comment: in that case you should put parallel controllers under throughput controllers